# How to set contentview as R.layout.activity_main on button click

Tags: java, android, xml

I am a beginner at android programming.
I have my layout.main_activity in xml and a View in onCreate() method.
If I `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` How can I bring my View to front on a button click (button is present in R.layout.activity_main)

Here's my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    View v = new View(this);
    //declarations
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //code
        View v = new View(this)  {
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                //things to do
            }
        };
    };
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onClick(View vi){ 
    setContentView(v);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put that setContentView() method first or else your app will crash. If you want to open something on a button press then create a new Intent to launch that xml file.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Here on button press it will start the new activity

Comment: yea i learned android using this very answer. Once you learn this everything will fall into place. I released my app maybe you could check it out and if you need help with anything else dont hesitate to ask . https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartutils.tapdat&hl=en

Comment: i set it to all countries

Comment: nice app ..
pretty handy if u wanna talk during serious lectures.. ;)

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mosin.bug&hl=en
checkout the app which u help me complete..
its my first app..
play,enjoy and leave a review..

Answer (score 0):

You should only call `setContentView()` once at the beginning of `onCreate()` and no where else. If you want to show a different screen, create a new Activity subclass and start it with `startActivity()`. See [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) for more details.